# Using the less-than (<) symbol on Python's subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Directly on console I can encrypt and decrypt a string using openssl. As openssl requires an input file, I can tell it to get this from the echo I enter using the less-than symbol (<), like this:

Encrypt:

```
# openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in <(echo "helloworld") -a -k 12345678 -S 12345678 -iv 12345678
U2FsdGVkX18SNFZ4AAAAAKJTAirWf4KnDHYXlIF/87Y=
```

Decrypt:

```
# openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in <(echo "U2FsdGVkX18SNFZ4AAAAAKJTAirWf4KnDHYXlIF/87Y=") -d -a -k 12345678 -S 12345678 -iv 12345678
helloworld
```

Using Python I need to decrypt the string "U2FsdGVkX18SNFZ4AAAAAKJTAirWf4KnDHYXlIF/87Y=" and to print out "helloworld".

So far, I've tried this but I get always an error:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
cmd = 'openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in < (echo U2FsdGVkX18SNFZ4AAAAAKJTAirWf4KnDHYXlIF/87Y=) ' \
      '-d -a -k 12345678 -S 12345678 -iv 12345678'
x = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = x.communicate()[0]
print output
```

The error I get is: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Is there a way of achieving what I need?

Comment: `'openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in <(echo U2FsdGVkX18SNFZ4AAAAAKJTAirWf4KnDHYXlIF/87Y=) -d -a -k 12345678 -S 12345678 -iv 12345678'`

Comment: @Goyo .. Same error as above

Answer (score 2):

```
$ openssl enc --help
...
 -in file           Input file to read from (default stdin)
```

The command reads from `stdin` by default, you only need the `-in` parameter if you want `openssl` to read from a file *instead of* a pipe. I.e., by default this would do just fine too:

```
echo helloworld | openssl enc ...
# (no -in!)
```

The Python equivalent of this is:

```
x = Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = x.communicate(input='helloworld')[0]
```

(Again, no `-in` in `cmd`, let `openssl` read from `stdin`.)

Comment: I tried:
cmd = 'openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -k 12345678 -S 12345678 -iv 12345678'
x = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = x.communicate(input='U2FsdGVkX18SNFZ4AAAAAKJTAirWf4KnDHYXlIF/87Y=')[0]
print output

It brings me the same error.

Comment: You get "`/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`" from a command that does not include a `(`?!

Comment: I tried it again.. on a new computer, I get: "error reading input file". This sound more like an openssl error that cannot read stdin..

Comment: I think the problem resides on my openssl version.. on the help I got only this:

Comment: # openssl enc --help
-in <file>     input file

Comment: Without " to read from (default stdin)" as in your version of openssl

Comment: That works..  `echo "helloworld" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -k 12345678 -S 12345678 -iv 12345678`
returns: U2FsdGVkX18SNFZ4AAAAAKJTAirWf4KnDHYXlIF/87Y=

Answer (score 2):

Python is using `/bin/sh` by default to execute your command, but `sh` doesn't support the `<(...)` construct. You need to [use another shell](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/04/how-use-bash-shell-python-subprocess-instead-binsh/) (e.g. `bash`) instead, using `Popen`'s `executable` argument:

```
>>> x = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, executable='/bin/bash')
>>> x.communicate()
('U2FsdGVkX18SNFZ4AAAAAKJTAirWf4KnDHYXlIF/87Y=\n', None)
```

(That said, I would consider exploring [deceze's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503581/789671) of using a more pythonic method of providing input.)

Comment: @Ñhosko See my edit, though... this can get you by, but using Python's built-in input pathways would be a more flexible solution.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tested the command directly in a shell to see if it worked?

Finally, there's nothing that seems to block you from separating those calls.

You could `echo U2FsdGVkX18SNFZ4AAAAAKJTAirWf4KnDHYXlIF/87Y` and pass this to `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` from an other subprocess, that has the openssl command in it.

Comment: No, that won't work. `<(...)` is syntax specific to some shells, not (multiple) arguments to be provided to `openssl`.

Comment: what about stdin?

Comment: On a shell it works:    openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in <(echo "U2FsdGVkX18SNFZ4AAAAAKJTAirWf4KnDHYXlIF/87Y=") -d -a -k 12345678 -S 12345678 -iv 12345678